# Rxjs - How to find out the min value in a Observable<number>[]?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a observable array, `Observable<number>[]` and I want to find out the minimum one and display it in template by async pipe.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Something like `forkJoin(obsArray).pipe(map(numbers => Math.min(...numbers)))`

Comment: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/min

Comment: merge(...arr).pipe(min())

Comment: Slightly depends. Do you want to wait for all observables to emit 1st value? How do you want to handle case where one observable doesn't emit? And if minimum number coming from one observable now emits a higher value do you want new minimum in that case or do you want overall minimum ever seen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min` operator

See the [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/min)